# problem implementing "useDispatch" hook with "redux-thunk"

Tags: react-redux

I have tried to implement a simple logout functionality using "**useDispatch**" hook. I am using '**redux-thunk**' as middleware. I want to change isAuthenticated in my state using Logout button to false. but I encounter this error:

TypeError: dispatch is not a function

```
// Logout action:
export const logout = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: LOGOUT });
};

// Logout reducer:
case 'LOGOUT':
  localStorage.removeItem('token');
   return {
    ...state,
    token: null,
    isAuthenticated: false,
    loading: false
    };

// inside component:
const dispatch = useDispatch();

<a onClick={dispatch(logout)} href='#!'>
```

this way of using 'useDispatch' worked just fine when I implemented axios in async format. there is a hint when I hover on useDispatch which states:

> Note for redux-thunk users: the return type of the returned dispatch
>   functions for thunks is incorrect. However, it is possible to get a
>   correctly typed dispatch function by creating your own custom hook
>   typed from the store's dispatch function like this: *const
>   useThunkDispatch = () => useDispatch();*

I dont know how can I fix this error: 
**TypeError: dispatch is not a function**

P.S: this is my first question in stackoverflow. :)

many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to SO. Look at this line:

> `<a onClick={dispatch(logout)} href='#!'>`

The `dispatch(logout)` part is executing immediately rather than providing a function for `onClick` to execute. You need to do this:

> `<a onClick={() => dispatch(logout)} href='#!'>`

Which is an anonymous function that doesn't execute immediately, but only gets executed by the `onClick` event.